# How to Run JXCORE on windows

Tags: node.js, jxcore

i want to create to desktop standalone app running on node.js. 
After long search i found jxcore helps to build node.js native apps. I want to know how to install the jxcore. I have downloaded zip folder from jxcore site and unzip the folder it contains jx executable file. On running this nothing happens. how to install jxcore.

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download the Windows Setup from https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-release ?

You should see it's label as given below;
**Windows Setup (32/64/SM/V8)  ....**

Once you install it, you can open the terminal (Run->cmd) and type **jx**